# PHP - ftp_put + Copy Entire Folder Structure

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to create an FTP script that will copy a local folder structure upto an FTP point. Basically to update a website.

I have been testing the following code (have changed the user/pass/domain) but the connection doesn't fail and appears to be working.

```
   $server = 'ftp.domainname.co';
   $ftp_user_name = 'user';
   $ftp_user_pass = 'pass';
   $dest = '.';
   $source = '.';
   $mode = 'FTP_ASCII';


   $connection = ftp_connect($server);

   $login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

   if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

   $upload = ftp_put($connection, $dest, $source, $mode);

   if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

   ftp_close($connection);
```

I'm confident the point that is breaking is the ftp_put line.
My questions are:

1. Can ftp_put upload an entire directory structure with files etc or is this just to upload one file at a time? Is there a different command I should be using?
2. I think I have something wrong with these variables:

   ```
       $dest = '.';
       $source = '.';
       $mode = 'FTP_ASCII';
   ```

I believe mode is correct.

$dest - this is just the root of the ftp server being ftp.domainname.co - should I put the ftp server name or what goes here.

$source - this is a the current local path - I've also tried the full C:\etc path.

I get this error:
Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 4 to be long

any help would be great.

thx

Comment: If you can use another protocol, consider using an rsync-over-SSH method instead of FTP. It's a lot safer, it's deterministic, resilient to many common failures, and it's secure by default in most cases.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not working because it is expecting a file, not a directory.
[PHP manual for ftp_put](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) has some code examples for recursive file uploads posted by commenters.

Here is one of them (note that it requires a full path):

```
function ftp_putAll($conn_id, $src_dir, $dst_dir) {
    $d = dir($src_dir);
    while($file = $d->read()) { // do this for each file in the directory
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") { // to prevent an infinite loop
            if (is_dir($src_dir."/".$file)) { // do the following if it is a directory
                if (!@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file)) {
                    ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file); // create directories that do not yet exist
                }
                ftp_putAll($conn_id, $src_dir."/".$file, $dst_dir."/".$file); // recursive part
            } else {
                $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $dst_dir."/".$file, $src_dir."/".$file, FTP_BINARY); // put the files
            }
        }
    }
    $d->close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 4 to be long
```

Well, to me it seems quite obvious: parameter 4 needs to be 'long' (or: a number). In this case it can also be a `CONSTANT` that represents that number, such as `ftp_put(x, y, z, FTP_ASCII)`. Not with quotes ('), like you did it: `ftp_put(x, y, z, 'FTP_ASCII')`

Answer (score 0):

For those that are still look for an answer : I made a gist to do that :
[FTPRecursiveFolderUpload.php](https://gist.github.com/Tchekda/40736c320d3733d9e4522a57bb24c9f7) that will be updated but here is the main code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
//Define vars
$ftp_server = getenv('server'); // As ftp.server.com
$ftp_user_name = getenv('user'); // As user
$ftp_password = getenv('password'); //As password
$remoteDir = getenv('remoteDir'); // As /home/user/ftp/ WITH the last slash!!
$dir = getenv('dir'); // As folder/download WITHOUT the last slash!!
function make_directory($ftp_stream, $dir){ //Create FTP directory if not exists
    // if directory already exists or can be immediately created return true
    if (ftp_chdir ($ftp_stream, $dir) || @ftp_mkdir($ftp_stream, $dir)) return true;
    // otherwise recursively try to make the directory
    if (!make_directory($ftp_stream, dirname($dir))) return false;
    // final step to create the directory
    return ftp_mkdir($ftp_stream, $dir);
}
if (boolval(getenv('ssl')) == true){ // Is it and SSL Connection
    $conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server, intval(getenv('port'))); // Create FTP Secure Connection
}else{
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, intval((getenv('port')? getenv('port') : 21))); // Create FTP  Connection
}
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_password); //Login in with credentials
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { // If login fails
    echo "FTP Connection failed to server $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name <br>\r\n";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Connected to Server $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name <br>\n";
}
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); // Set Passive mode
$recursiveFileResearch = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)); // Get all files in folder and subfolder in the selected directory
$files = array();
foreach ($recursiveFileResearch as $file) {
    if ($file->isDir()){
        continue;
    }
    $files[] = str_replace($dir . "/", "", str_replace('\\', '/', $file->getPathname())); // Store the file without backslashes (Windows..) and without the root directory
}
if (count($files) > 0) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        make_directory($conn_id, $remoteDir . dirname($file)); // Create directory if not exists
        ftp_chdir ($conn_id, $remoteDir . dirname($file)); // Go to that FTP directory
        echo "Current directory : " . ftp_pwd($conn_id) . " for file : " . basename($file)
            . " that could be found locally : " . $dir . "/" . $file . "<br>\n"; // Some logs to chekc the process
        ftp_put($conn_id, basename($file), $dir . "/"  . $file, FTP_BINARY); //Upload the file to current FTP directory
        echo "Uploaded " . basename($file) . "<br>\n"; // Some logs to chekc the process
    }
} else {
    echo "Didn't found any folder/files to send in directory : " . $dir . "<br>\n";
}
ftp_close($conn_id); // Close FTP Connection
echo "Finished <br>\n";
```

Comment: @AntonMenshov Done, i'm new so i'm not very used to these rules. Thank you