# Upload a ZIP file and UNZIP ftp folder via PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp, zip, unzip

I want to make a form where you can fill FTP login server and get option to upload ZIP file. The script works apart from the last part (UNZIP the file) I want to perform UNZIP uploaded file. Does anyone know what is the problem? TIA

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$ftp_server = $ftp = $_POST['ftp'];
$ftp_user_name = $username = $_POST['username'];
$ftp_user_pass = $password = $_POST['password'];   


 if (!empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {
$ch = curl_init();

$file1 = $localfile = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$fp = fopen($file1, 'r');

$file = '/htdocs/file.zip';
// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to upload $file
if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded ftp://".$username.":".$password."@".$ftp.$file."\n";

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($file); 
    $zip->extractTo('ftp://'.$username.':'.$password.'@'.$ftp.'/htdocs'); 
    $zip->close();

} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection and the file handler
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);
 }  
}
?>

    <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div>
                <label for="upload">Select file</label>
                <input name="upload" type="file" />
                <br> Ftp Server:
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="ftp" value="<?php if(isset($ftp)){ echo $ftp; } ?>">
                <br> Username:
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($username)){ echo $username; } ?>">
                <br> Password:
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php if(isset($password)){ echo $password; }else{ echo '123456';} ?>">

                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

THE ERROR

> Successfully uploaded
>
> > ftp://***:***@ftp.***.com/htdocs/file.zip  Warning:
> >     ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in
> >     C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 29
> >
> > Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in
> >     C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php on line 30

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ZipArchive` does not support URL wrappers.

And your code does not make much sense anyway:

- You first upload `$localfile` to FTP server as `/htdocs/file.zip`

  ```
  $file = '/htdocs/file.zip';
  ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)
  ```
- And then you try to open `/htdocs/file.zip`, as it it were a local file

  ```
  $zip->open($file);
  ```

  But such local file does not exists.
- And then you try to extract that non existing file to FTP URL. And that's not supported.

  See [ZipArchive::open(): support stream wrappers](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68621). It's about `open`, but if `open` does not support wrappers, the `extactTo` won't either (it's a way more difficult to support). See a [comment by cmb](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68621#1433424133):

  > Anyhow, ZipArchive::open() is not supposed to accept any stream
  > wrapper URLs, but only real file paths. Its documentation doesn't
  > tell otherwise, and neither does the man page on "Supported
  > Protocols and Wrappers"[1]:
  >
  > > | PHP comes with many built-in wrappers for various URL-style
  > > | protocols for use with the filesystem functions [...]
  >
  > However, ZipArchive::open() is not a filesystem function for that
  > matter.
  >
  > So, actually, this is not a bug, not even a documentation bug in
  > the strict sense. Therefore I'm changing to feature request.

---

As your code is just wrong, its difficult to guess, what you are actually trying to do. I can imagine these two possibilities.

- You wanted to upload a ZIP file to FTP server and unzip it there. It's simply [not possible to unzip a ZIP file on an FTP server](https://superuser.com/q/479661/213663).
- You wanted to extract a local ZIP to FTP server. While it may seem that it's possible with use of URL wrapper in the `ZipArchive:extractTo` call, it's not. As I've shown above. Nor there is any other way to extract local ZIP file to FTP server with some simple one-liner in PHP.

  All you can do, is to extract the ZIP file locally (on the web server); and then upload it file-by-file to the FTP server.

  - Create a temporary folder and extract (`ZipArchive::extractTo`) the ZIP archive there.
  - Upload the temporary folder to the FTP server.

    See [PHP - ftp_put + Copy Entire Folder Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8773843/850848).
  - Delete the temporary folder.

---

Also note that you upload the file using ASCII mode. A ZIP format is binary. By uploading binary file in ASCII mode, you damage it.

```
ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII);
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually none of the FTP clients can extract or unzip archive files on the FTP server because there is no such command in FTP. However, net2ftp makes it possible by downloading the archive file from your web server, extracts the files in their server and then upload all the files back to your server. Hence, you might notice that it takes quite a long time for net2ftp to complete uploading if there are thousands of files in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 steps =>

Step 1: Upload your zip file (Uploaded.zip) to the ftp server. Code =>
`ftp_put($ftp, $remote_file, "Upload,zip", FTP_BINARY) ;`
Step 2: Upload 1 more file to your ftp server let's name it Extractor.php which has the code to extract the zip file.
Code =>

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('uploaded.zip');
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('extract/path/');
    $zip->close();
    echo "Extracted" ;
    unlink("uploaded.zip");
} else {
    echo "Zip Corrupted" ;
}
```

Step 3:
Call the Extractor.php using curl just after uploading both files.
Code =>

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://url/where/it/will/be/displayed/Extractor.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output) ;
```

Hope, it will be helpful for you as well :)